# What do the Android camera zoom numbers mathematically represent?

Tags: android, camera, zooming

I'm trying to write a basic augmented reality app in Android, but I'm running into some trouble doing platform-uncoupled calculations because I don't know how to interpret the zoom levels on Android.

The zoom levels range from 0 - params.getMaxZoom(), but I can't find any documentation about what those zoom levels actually mean (for example, zoom level 0 is obviously 0% zoomed in, but is zoom level 1 like 10% zoomed in?)

Are the zoom levels totally undefined and arbitrary abstractions?  I hope not - that would make zoomed-in AR pretty hopeless.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

D'oh - looks like I just needed to read the documentation more closely.  The answer can be found here:
[getZoomRatios ()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#getZoomRatios())