# What is the angle the WP7 Camera sees?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, camera

Same question as [Determine angle of view of smartphone camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3261776/determine-angle-of-view-of-smartphone-camera), applied for WP7.
Can't seem to find an appropriate method, and I don't want to put my users through calibrating it themselves (if possible).
Thanks

Comment: this is also a nice blog about the sensors in the phone. I believe that you might find what you are looking for there instead of looking in the camera area. http://developer.nokia.com/community/wiki/Qibla_Compass_for_Windows_Phone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please see this post

[How to find out the aperture angle of an android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7983444/how-to-find-out-the-aperture-angle-of-an-android-camera)

in WP7, there is no API function to get that, and no other option than

- Ask user introduce it (they never know)
- Make a list of phones you support and obtain/measure it for each one. Store it in your app. (crazy!)

(I am doing the same kind of stuff and we invested a lot in finding automatic calibration methods, without success.)

**EDIT**

Cheers and love for bill and microsoft co.

Comment: Obtain from manufacturers by contacting them individually, or by measuring each phone

Answer (score 3):

I dont know how to get the angle of the camera, but I do have an app that will calculate the tilt of the phone based on the Yaw/Roll/Pitch.

```
namespace PhoneUtilities.Utilities
{
    public class AccelerometerMath
    {
        public static double RadianToDegree(double radians)
        {

            return radians * (180 / Math.PI);
        }

        public static double Pitch(AccelerometerReading e)
        {
            return RadianToDegree((Math.Atan(e.Acceleration.X / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(e.Acceleration.Y, 2) + Math.Pow(e.Acceleration.Z, 2)))));
        }

        public static double Roll(AccelerometerReading e)
        {
            return RadianToDegree((Math.Atan(e.Acceleration.Y / Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(e.Acceleration.X, 2) + Math.Pow(e.Acceleration.Z, 2)))));
        }

        public static double Yaw(AccelerometerReading e)
        {
            return RadianToDegree((Math.Atan(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow(e.Acceleration.X, 2) + Math.Pow(e.Acceleration.Y, 2)) / e.Acceleration.Z)));
        }
    }
}
```

The calculations were able to get me the angle of the tilt, here is an example I use for some trig calculation Cos(angle) = adj/hyp:

```
private double CalcUpAdj(AccelerometerReading reading)
{
    double angle = PhoneUtilities.Utilities.AccelerometerMath.Yaw(reading);

    //Get the angleNeeded for calculation
    double angleNeeded = Math.Abs(angle);
    double adj = CalcAdj(angleNeeded);

    tbAngle.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", angleNeeded) + (char)176;
    textBlockAdj.Text = adj.ToString();

    return adj;
}

private double CalcAdj(double angleNeeded)
{
    double number;
    if (double.TryParse(tbHyp.Text, out number))
    {
        double hyp = number;
        double adj = Math.Cos(Math.PI * angleNeeded / 180) * hyp;

        tbAngle.Text = String.Format("{0:0.00}", angleNeeded) + (char)176;

        textBlockAdj.Text = adj.ToString();
        return adj;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I dont know if this will help you with your camera, but I imagine if you knew the dimensions of the screen you could calculate the angle based on the tilt of the phone.  Hopefully you find this helpful.

Comment: Nice, informative post, though not related to what I was looking for.