# scale shape coordinates from custom view to adapt different screen sizes

Tags: android, scaling, object-detection, camera-api

I'm working on an app to detect objects in real time using the camera preview and then take a picture and display it in an other activity and a bounding box (most cases a polygon) will be drawn over the detected object.

I managed to do that and everything works fine. Now I'm trying to speed up the detection process by setting a small camera preview size and taking a picture with a bigger resolution by changing the camera parameters. But the coordinates that I will be getting must be scaled to match the big picture size.

In my case :

- Camera Preview Size is always : **640x480** (the coordinates matches this size)
- Picture taken Size will be chosen using the method mentioned in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26958110/android-taken-photo-is-bigger-than-the-preview).
- In most cases the Picture size will be so big (in my phone it's **4260x3120**) and I'm resizing the canvas so it fits the screen

For the canvas size I'm using this to get the screen resolution :

```
public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}

public static int getScreenHeight() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().heightPixels;
}
```

my xml file looks like this :

```
<LinearLayout>
     ....
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      ....
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

      ....
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp">

        <packagename.CropImageView
            android:id="@+id/scannedImage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round" />

    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and in my custom view class **CropImageView** I'm passing four coordinates to the **onDraw** method and drawing **paths** between them.

**Note** : I saw a couple of questions about approximately the same subject but I couldn't relate to them since  I couldn't a use case like mine. Any information, help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all I needed to do is to find the scale factors for `Y` and `X` following this :

```
    scaleFactorY = (float) newWidth / oldWidth;
    scaleFactorX = (float) newHeight / oldHeight;
```

then multiply the coordinates with those factors. Also you need to make sure that the `preview size`, `picture size` and the `container` that will hold the picture have the same aspect ratio or else you will get misplaced coordinates.

to get the aspect ration you need simply need to do this : `width / height`.